# Scala - Future "Out of memory"

Tags: scala, concurrency, out-of-memory, future

So I have to following code:

```
case class ResultEntry(destination: String,
                           from: LocalDate,
                           to: LocalDate,
                           data: Data)
    
    val destinations = Seq(
      "New York",
      "Scranton",
      "Stamford",
      "Jamaica",
    )
    val dates = 0.to(30).map(v => LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1).plusDays(v))

    Await.result(
      Future
        .sequence(for {
          destination <- destinations
          fromDate <- dates
          toDate <- dates if (toDate.isAfter(fromDate))
          score = Future(
            blocking(
              SnelDwight.calculateVacationScore(destination, fromDate, toDate)))

        } yield {
          score.map { score =>
            ResultEntry(destination, fromDate, toDate, score)
          }

        })
        .map { results =>
          results.groupBy(_.destination).map {
            case (destination, results) =>
              val min = results.minBy(_.data.score)
              println(s"${destination} : ${min}")

          }
        },
      Duration.Inf
    )
```

This code will throw "Out of memory" exception. I need to solve that problem, but keep the computations as concurrent as possible. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Using `blocking` causes a new thread to be created each time, rather than using an existing thread from a pool of threads. This avoids the danger of blocking every thread in the pool and preventing new `Future`s from running.

In this example you are creating nearly 2,000 threads which may well cause the memory error.

If the calculation isn't really blocking then just remove `blocking`.

If the calculation *is* blocking then you need to batch multiple calculations on a single thread. For example, do all the `toDate`s in one `Future` (which is probably more efficient anyway).

Comment: can you show me a code example with `toDate`?